# Understanding diagonal rescaling in multiplicative update rules for NMF

Tags: machine-learning, least-squares, unsupervised-learning, matrix-decomposition, non-negative-matrix-factorization

**SUMMARY**

How does the diagonal rescaling fit into the derivation of a multiplicative update rule for non-negative matrix factorization (NMF)?

**DESCRIPTION**

The NMF problem aims to find non-negative matrix factors $W$ and $H$ from a non-negative matrix $V$ such that $V \approx WH$.

Having an additive update rule

$H \leftarrow H + \eta_{H}[W^TV - W^TWH] \qquad (1)$

and a multiplicative update rule

$H \leftarrow H \frac{W^TV}{W^TWH} \qquad (2)$

for $H$, the [paper](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2000/file/f9d1152547c0bde01830b7e8bd60024c-Paper.pdf) states that if

> we diagonally rescale the variables and set $\eta_H=\frac{H}{W^TWH}$, then we obtain the [multiplicative] update rule for $H$ [from the additive rule]. Note that this rescaling results in a multiplicative factor with the positive component of the gradient in the denominator and the absolute value of the negative component in the numerator of the factor

of the form $\theta \leftarrow \theta \frac{\nabla^-_\theta f(\theta)}{\nabla^+_\theta f(\theta)} \qquad (3)$.

**QUESTION**

1. What is the diagonal rescaling exactly? And what role does it play in the derivation of the multiplicative update rule?

   I read a post on the derivation [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/351359/deriving-multiplicative-update-rules-for-nmf) but could not find any explanations about the rescaling. It would be very much helpful if anyone can explain why rescaling is necessary and the mathematical equations associated with it.
2. How does rescaling make a multiplicative factor with the form of Equation (3)?
3. Lastly, it is said that NMF factors are invariant to rescaling as the degree of freedom of diagonal rescaling is always present (c.f., [here](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ejordan/papers/ding-li-jordan-pami.pdf), [here](https://wiki.math.uwaterloo.ca/statwiki/index.php?title=convex_and_Semi_Nonnegative_Matrix_Factorization)). How does this statement relates to the derivation here?

Reference: "Algorithms for Non-negative Matrix Factorizaton" [Lee & Seung (2000)](https://proceedings.neurips.cc/paper/2000/file/f9d1152547c0bde01830b7e8bd60024c-Paper.pdf)